# Assign value before free()

Tags: c

In C function, below piece of code is there:

```
  val *val_ptr;

  for (val_ptr = *(val **)vl; val_ptr->id; val_ptr++)
    free(val_ptr->str);
```

Somehow, I can not change these piece of code. I need to write the code before this, to allocate memory to val_str->str. I have written below code:

```
  for (val_ptr = *(val **)vl; val_ptr->id; val_ptr++)
  {
     char* abc = "testing";
     val_ptr->str = strdup(abc);
  }
```

It is throwing error. Can anyone please suggest on this?

Comment: What is `vl`? What is the thrown error?

Comment: [New Thread 0xf7735710 (LWP 6134)]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xf7735710 (LWP 6134)]
0x00611025 in _int_malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6

Comment: char        *vl          = NULL;

Comment: OK, you have found the problem, now you can fix it.

Comment: Can you confirm that it is actually `strdup` that leads to the segfault ?

Answer (score 0):

Val should be a structure who looks like this

```
typedef struct s_val
{
  char *str;
  int id;
}               val;
```

if vl == NULL, it means that it points to nothing... so you can't access to nothing with it.
This is the reason why you segfault.

You have to allocate the memory you need with malloc (i suppose that you just learned pointer and malloc).

```
int number_of_val_i_want;
vl = malloc(sizeof(val) * number_of_val_i_want);
```

After that, you must allocate all the str pointer, you can use strdup if you want, but i think that trainning to use malloc should be a great idea (recode strdup should be a good exercice to beginning ;)).

I let you think about the stop condition of the for loops.

I don't forget, you have to free vl after the imposed for loops !